# Why will my list of network interfaces not print?

Tags: java, collections

I'm trying to print a list of network interfaces (eventually to store them in a String array of some kind). The following code will only print the list of interfaces if the

```
    String[] networkInterfaces = new String[Collections.list(nets).size()];
```

line is not there. It will print the entire list if that single line is not there.

```
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nets = null;
    try {
        nets = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(Collections.list(nets).size());
    String[] networkInterfaces = new String[Collections.list(nets).size()];

    for (NetworkInterface netint : Collections.list(nets)) {
        System.out.println(netint.getName());
    }
```

Sorry for lack of tags on this question, I wasn't sure what was appropriate. Any idea why this occurs? I've modified it such that the collection is saved into an ArrayList (which seems to be fine)

```
    ArrayList<NetworkInterface> netints = Collections.list(nets);
```

but I'm still curious as to why the other way didn't work. Thanks :)

Comment: Just a code quality comment: you **really** should extract `Collections.list(nets)` into a local variable, it would help readability of this snippet largely, as you use it on almost every lines...

Comment: @ppeterka: Not just code quality as it turns out, since this would also resolve the issue!

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle LOL, I didn't even read the snippet in full length, I felt tired to do that (because of bad code quality :) ), just tried to help the guy get ahead... A nice example when clean coding pays off in a totally direct and explicit way...

Comment: @ppeterka thanks, I did this prior to your comment to make it easier to read, and found it solved the issue too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short it's because an `Enumeration` is a stateful iterator.

The first time that you call `Collections.list(nets)`, this library method will loop through the `nets` enumeration, pulling out elements until the enumeration has no more to return.  This works as expected, and the returned list is as you'd expect.

However, on the next line you call `Collections.list(nets)` *again*.  This pulls all of the elements from `nets`, **which is now exhausted**, and so "correctly" creates an empty list from an enumeration with no (more) elements.

One way to fix this problem would be to immediately convert `nets` into a list, and then reference that list everywhere.  So you could change the start of your code to:

```
List<NetworkInterface> nets = null;
try {
    nets = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
}
...
```

And then just reference the `nets` list later on instead of wrapping an enumeration each time.